# Testing useContext() with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-hooks

I think I found another way to test a component using the `useContext` hook. I have seen a few tutorials that test if a value can be successfully passed down to a child component from a parent Context Provider but did not find tutorials on the child updating the context value.

My solution is to render the root parent component along with the provider, because the state is ultimately changed in the root parent component and then passed to the provider which then passes it to all child components. Right?

The tests seem to pass when they should and not pass when they shouldn't.
Can someone explain why this is or isn't a good way to test the `useContext` hook?

The root parent component:

```
...
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("Some Text")

  const changeText = () => {
    setState("Some Other Text")
  }
...

  <h1> Basic Hook useContext</h1>
     <Context.Provider value={{changeTextProp: changeText,
                               stateProp: state
                                 }} >
        <TestHookContext />
     </Context.Provider>
)}
```

The context object:

```
import React from 'react';

const Context = React.createContext()

export default Context
```

The child component:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

import Context from '../store/context';

const TestHookContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(Context)

  return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={context.changeTextProp}>
        Change Text
    </button>
      <p>{context.stateProp}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And the tests:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestHookContext from '../test_hook_context.js';
import {render, fireEvent, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react';
import App from '../../../App'

import Context from '../../store/context';

afterEach(cleanup)

it('Context is updated by child component', () => {

   const { container, getByText } = render(<App>
                                            <Context.Provider>
                                             <TestHookContext />
                                            </Context.Provider>
                                           </App>);

   console.log(container)
   expect(getByText(/Some/i).textContent).toBe("Some Text")

   fireEvent.click(getByText("Change Text"))

   expect(getByText(/Some/i).textContent).toBe("Some Other Text")
})
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem with the approach that you mention is coupling.
Your Context to be tested, depends on `<TestHookContext/>` and `<App/>`

As Kent C. Dodds, the author of react-testing-library, has a full article on ["Test Isolation with React"](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/test-isolation-with-react) if you want to give it a read.

### TLDR: [Demo repo here](https://github.com/jonatankruszewski/boiler-plate-testing-react-useContext)

### How to test Context

- Export a `<ContextProvider>` component that holds the state and returns `<MyContext.Provider value={{yourWhole: "State"}}>{children}<MyContext.Provider/>` This is the component that we are going to test for the provider.
- On the components that consume that Context, create a MockContextProvider to replace the original one. You want to test the component in isolation.
- You can test the whole app workflow to by testing the root component.

### Testing Auth Provider

Let's say we have a component that provides Auth using context the following way:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoggedin, setIsLoggedin] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const login = (user) => {
    setIsLoggedin(true);
    setUser(user);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setIsLoggedin(false);
    setUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ logout, login, isLoggedin, user }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

The test file would look like:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import AuthProvider, { AuthContext } from "./AuthProvider";
import { useContext } from "react";

const CustomTest = () => {
  const { logout, login, isLoggedin, user } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <div data-testid="isLoggedin">{JSON.stringify(isLoggedin)}</div>
      <div data-testid="user">{JSON.stringify(user)}</div>
      <button onClick={() => login("demo")} aria-label="login">
        Login
      </button>
      <button onClick={logout} aria-label="logout">
        LogOut
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

test("Should render initial values", () => {
  render(
    <AuthProvider>
      <CustomTest />
    </AuthProvider>
  );

  expect(screen.getByTestId("isLoggedin")).toHaveTextContent("false");
  expect(screen.getByTestId("user")).toHaveTextContent("null");
});

test("Should Login", () => {
  render(
    <AuthProvider>
      <CustomTest />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
  const loginButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "login" });
  fireEvent.click(loginButton);
  expect(screen.getByTestId("isLoggedin")).toHaveTextContent("true");
  expect(screen.getByTestId("user")).toHaveTextContent("demo");
});

test("Should Logout", () => {
  render(
    <AuthProvider>
      <CustomTest />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
  const loginButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "logout" });
  fireEvent.click(loginButton);
  expect(screen.getByTestId("isLoggedin")).toHaveTextContent("false");
  expect(screen.getByTestId("user")).toHaveTextContent("null");
});
```

### Testing Component that consumes Context

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthProvider";

const Welcome = () => {
  const { logout, login, isLoggedin, user } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {user && <div>Hello {user}</div>}
      {!user && <div>Hello Anonymous Goose</div>}
      {!isLoggedin && (
        <button aria-label="login" onClick={() => login("Jony")}>
          Log In
        </button>
      )}
      {isLoggedin && (
        <button aria-label="logout" onClick={() => logout()}>
          Log out
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

We will mock the AuthContext value by providing one of our own:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import Welcome from "./welcome";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthProvider";

// A custom provider, not the AuthProvider, to test it in isolation.
// This customRender will be a fake AuthProvider, one that I can controll to abstract of AuthProvider issues.

const customRender = (ui, { providerProps, ...renderOptions }) => {
  return render(
    <AuthContext.Provider value={providerProps}>{ui}</AuthContext.Provider>,
    renderOptions
  );
};

describe("Testing Context Consumer", () => {
  let providerProps;
  beforeEach(
    () =>
      (providerProps = {
        user: "C3PO",
        login: jest.fn(function (user) {
          providerProps.user = user;
          providerProps.isLoggedin = true;
        }),
        logout: jest.fn(function () {
          providerProps.user = null;
          providerProps.isLoggedin = false;
        }),
        isLoggedin: true,
      })
  );

  test("Should render the user Name when user is signed in", () => {
    customRender(<Welcome />, { providerProps });
    expect(screen.getByText(/Hello/i)).toHaveTextContent("Hello C3PO");
  });

  test("Should render Hello Anonymous Goose when is NOT signed in", () => {
    providerProps.isLoggedin = false;
    providerProps.user = null;
    customRender(<Welcome />, { providerProps });
    expect(screen.getByText(/Hello/i)).toHaveTextContent(
      "Hello Anonymous Goose"
    );
  });

  test("Should render Logout button when user is signed in", () => {
    customRender(<Welcome />, { providerProps });
    expect(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "logout" })).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByRole("button", { name: "login" })).toBeNull();
  });

  test("Should render Login button when user is NOT signed in", () => {
    providerProps.isLoggedin = false;
    providerProps.user = null;
    customRender(<Welcome />, { providerProps });
    expect(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "login" })).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByRole("button", { name: "logout" })).toBeNull();
  });

  test("Should Logout when user is signed in", () => {
    const { rerender } = customRender(<Welcome />, { providerProps });
    const logout = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "logout" });
    expect(logout).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByRole("button", { name: "login" })).toBeNull();
    userEvent.click(logout);
    expect(providerProps.logout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    //Technically, re renders are responsability of the parent component, but since we are here...
    rerender(
      <AuthContext.Provider value={providerProps}>
        <Welcome />
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
    expect(screen.getByText(/Hello/i)).toHaveTextContent(
      "Hello Anonymous Goose"
    );
    expect(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "login" })).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByRole("button", { name: "logout" })).toBeNull();
  });

  test("Should Login when user is NOT signed in", () => {
    providerProps.isLoggedin = false;
    providerProps.user = null;
    const { rerender } = customRender(<Welcome />, { providerProps });
    const login = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "login" });
    expect(login).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByRole("button", { name: "logout" })).toBeNull();
    userEvent.click(login);
    expect(providerProps.login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    //Technically, re renders are responsability of the parent component, but since we are here...
    rerender(
      <AuthContext.Provider value={providerProps}>
        <Welcome />
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
    expect(screen.getByText(/Hello/i)).toHaveTextContent("Hello Jony");
    expect(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "logout" })).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByRole("button", { name: "login" })).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution. At first my attempts didn't work, but alas, it was a false negative as the tests kept running on a cached version of the files, not on the changes I was making.

For others trying this, useContext on the import of last file is not used, and not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your example/code is dead on. (Not sure you need to mount the wrapping `<App />` - you should just wrap in the Context Provider directly).

To your question:

> The tests seem to pass when they should and not pass when they shouldnt. Can someone explain why this is or isnt a good way to test the useContext() hook.

It *is* a good way to test when using `useContext()` because it looks like you have abstracted out your context so that your child (consuming) component and its test both use the same context. I don't see any reason why you would mock or emulate what the context provider is doing when (as you do in your example) you use the same context provider.

The React Testing Library docs [point out](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library#the-solution) that:

> The more your tests resemble the way your software is used, the more confidence they can give you.

Therefore, setting up your tests the same way you set up your components achieves that goal. If you have multiple tests in one app that do need to be wrapped in the same context, [this blog post](https://www.polvara.me/posts/mocking-context-with-react-testing-library/) has a neat solution for reusing that logic.